# Passing function with parameter into select clause Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to call function get_path() into select clause (function get_all_lelang()) but i don't know how to write it. Can you help me?

Here is my code.

```
public function get_path($kode_lelang){
    $result = $this->db->query("select gambar as gbr from proyek_pertanian NATURAL join lelang where kode_lelang='".$kode_lelang."'")->row_array();
    $path = 'http://localhost/sikonsorsium/'.$result['gbr'];

    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    return $base64;
}

public function get_all_lelang(){
    $sql = "SELECT ".$get_path(."lelang.kode_lelang".)." as binImg, member.*

    FROM `lelang` 
    LEFT JOIN `member` ON `lelang`.`id_member` = `member`.`id_member` 
    JOIN `proyek_pertanian` ON `lelang`.`kode_proyek` = `proyek_pertanian`.`kode_proyek` ";

     $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
     return $query->result();

}
```

[edited] i've trying this

```
 public function get_all_lelang(){
    $sql = "SELECT '".$this->get_path("lelang.kode_lelang")."' as binImg, member.*

    FROM `lelang` 
    LEFT JOIN `member` ON `lelang`.`id_member` = `member`.`id_member` 
    JOIN `proyek_pertanian` ON `lelang`.`kode_proyek` = `proyek_pertanian`.`kode_proyek` ";

     $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
     return $query->result();

}
```

but it returns different value, the wrong value. please check the binImg value.

(wrong)

```
"kode_lelang":"LLG-20160616-183314","binImg":"data:image\/;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+Cgo8aHRt
```

(right)

```
"kode_lelang":"LLG-20160616-183314","binImg":"data:image\/jpg;base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
```

Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need small correction,

Change

```
$get_path(."lelang.kode_lelang".)
```

To

```
$this->get_path("lelang.kode_lelang")
```

Comment: hey i have realized it not works at all. It return different value.
I dont know why. please see my edit

Comment: within controller it should work, your syntax `$get_path(."lelang.kode_lelang".)` is not correct, and `$this->get_path("lelang.kode_lelang")` is the way of calling method inside class

Comment: yes i've changed it. i've edited my question. please see it :)